# Warning from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created cloud functions for sending the notification and accessing the firestore database. I have followed links mentioned below for writing the cloud function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Now I received an email from firebase:

```
   "You are receiving this message because you are an owner of a Firebase project that sent a message via the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) endpoint in the last 28 days.
 Last year we announced that the GCM server and client APIs are deprecated. To prevent a disruption in your service, you must redirect your Cloud Messaging server requests to the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) endpoint at fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/ before May 29, 2019.
  We also recommend that you upgrade your client SDKs from GCM to the latest version of Firebase Cloud Messaging. Although existing app installations that use GCM methods will continue to function, GCM methods will not work when your app targets future Android versions (after Android Q)".
```

Now I am confused, what I am doing is right or not. I should do some changes in code or It is fine. Please suggest something .

Comment: This message doesn't have anything to do with Cloud Functions or Firestore. It has to do with your use of GCM, and you will need to migrate to FCM.

Comment: @DougStevenson , I am using FCM both Android App and Server. But I have received same email. If I am already using FCM Than why this email received.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't know much about FCM and GCM. Can you please clarify what I need to change. I am not sure about that I am using GCM or not.